# Eclipse Perspective Development - Extend CDT Perspective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perspective

Will keep the question simple, but its implications are much broader.

**Goal**

Create a '**My C/C++**' perspective plugin.

- this plugin is just the standard C/C++ plugin from CDT
- plus some view sizing, extra help menus, and (1) custom plug-in

**Need**

Essentially just a way to share a customized C/C++ perspective

- that includes a handful of my own plugins
- but still harnesses all the power of CDT (editors, builders, parsers, views, etc).

**Notes**

This is a very helpful perspective-plugin tutorial:

- [Eclipse Plug-in Development – Create a Perspective](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/eclipse-plug-in-development-creat-a-perspective/)

There must be a simple 'man/example/etc' out there. I've browsed all over the CDT plug-in manual to no avail:

- [CDT Plug-in Developer Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/projectTemplateEngine/exampletemplate.html)

Perhaps it has to do with the **org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions**, but it is not clear to me how that would work.

Answer (score 1):

`org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` on its own just lets you add new views, menu items, tool bar items and new wizard items to an **existing** perspective (such as the C/C++ perspective).

If you want to create a new perspective you will have to declare it with `org.eclipse.ui.perspectives` and then use the perspective factory class and `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` to declare all the views, menu items and so on that you want in the perspective. This will mean finding out the ids of the C/C++ items you want to include - which probably means looking at the CDT plugin.xml files and their perspective factory source.

Update:
The C/C++ Perspective will be declared in one the CDT plugin plugin.xml files using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectives` extension point. That declaration will give the name of the existing perspective factory class used. You may be able to extend this class (but if it is in an `internal` package this is not officially supported).

Comment: yes sir! I tried going down that path; but the listing is ENORMOUS! surely there is a simpler way; just a way to say 'make me a CDT perspective + A & B'.

Comment: Extend their perspective factory class, assuming there is one.

Comment: ehh; a little more detail please? to note - just gimme a nibble. if I figure it out from that, I'll post the result as an answer to the thread.